# How does UITableViewController change the table view's `adjustedContentInsets` when the keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

When a UITableView governed by a UITableViewController has cells with text fields in them, if the user taps in a text field, the table view scrolls to keep that text field above the keyboard.

How does it do that? I tried to figure it out by implementing this method with a bunch of logging:

```
override func scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("did adjust")
    print("contentInset", self.tableView.contentInset)
    print("indicatorInsets", self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets)
    print("adjustedContentInsets", self.tableView.adjustedContentInset)
    print("safe area", self.tableView.safeAreaInsets)
    print("additional safe area", self.additionalSafeAreaInsets)
}
```

Here's the output from before and after the tap-and-scroll:

```
did adjust
contentInset UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
indicatorInsets UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
adjustedContentInsets UIEdgeInsets(top: 64.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
safe area UIEdgeInsets(top: 64.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
additional safe area UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)

did adjust
contentInset UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
indicatorInsets UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
adjustedContentInsets UIEdgeInsets(top: 64.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 253.0, right: 0.0)
safe area UIEdgeInsets(top: 64.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
additional safe area UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

After the scroll, the `bottom` of the `adjustedContentInsets` has changed. But how? It's not a settable property. It's supposed to respond to the safe area, but the safe area has not changed. The `contentInset` has not changed. How is this accomplished? How would I do the same thing with my own scroll views? (My solution currently is to change the `contentInset`, but clearly the table view controller doesn't have to do that.)

Comment: I suspect that this might be one of those "Apple can do things we can't" situations.  Stepping through with the debugger reveals that the behaviour is implemented by (or at least related to) the private interface `UIAutoRespondingScrollViewControllerKeyboardSupport`; my guess is that they set a property that isn't exposed but is used in the calculation of the `adjustedContentInsets`

Comment: @Paulw11 I totally agree with your suspicion. I hadn't gotten as far as peeking at the private interface but that was going to be my next move. Thanks for doing that!